# ACL не работает для запрета для групп

Tags: доступ, c++, безопасность

Добрый день!
У меня есть программа, которая настраивает ACL для групп пользователей.
Проблема в том, что я могу настроить ACL всегда, когда разрешаю доступ для групп. Когда я запрещаю доступ хоть для одной группы, у меня возвращается ошибка 122.  А доступ к файлу - полный.
Для конкретных пользователей запрещать доступ получается - все работает.

В программе 1004-1007 - сиды пользователей, 1008 и 1009 - сиды двух групп.

**UPD**: Проблема решена. Может кому надо, не видела этого нигде в теории: в списках ACL команды, которые запрещают доступ должны быть ДО команд разрешающих доступ. Например, если я хочу запретить доступ одной группе, но разрешить второй, то надо сначала запретить, а потом разрешить. А не наоборот.